# Does CKEditor support writing html-formatted emails?

Tags: ckeditor, html-email, wysiwyg

Our users need to author html-formatted emails. As you may know, there are lots of idiosyncrasies specific to crafting html-formatted emails. For example, using inline CSS instead of external CSS files or embedded CSS in the  section, using nested tables instead of divs, etc.

Does the CKEditor officially support authoring html-formatted emails?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 1):

No and Yes.

No: there's no single checkbox: "create HTML emails"

Yes: you can configure most of the features to work the way that you want, it might be easy sometimes and with other features you might have to fight harder, but it's up to you to learn how it works.